# Nested relation whereHas in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, wherehas

I wanna ask about some nested relation using `whereHas` query in laravel, well for the first I will explain the model first before I going through into my main case.

this is my model :

**StockIn.php**

```
class StockIn extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = "id_stock_in";

    /* this only column that I wanna show, and skip the else column */
    protected $fillable = ['stock_in_id_type'];

    public function type_of_items() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TypeOfitem', 'stock_in_id_type');
    }
}
```

**TypeOfItem.php**

```
class TypeOfItem extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = "id_type_item";

    /* this only column that I wanna show, and skip the else column */
    protected $fillable = ['type_id_item'];

    public function items() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'type_id_item');
    }

    public function stock_ins() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\StockIn');
    }
}
```

**Item.php**

```
class Item extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = "id_item";

    /* this only column that I wanna show, and skip the else column */
    protected $fillable = ['item_id_common_unit'];

    public function common_units() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\CommonUnit', 'item_id_common_unit');
    }

    public function type_of_items() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\TypeOfItem');
    }
}
```

**CommonUnit.php**

```
class CommonUnit extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = "id_common_unit";

    /* this only column that I wanna show, and skip the else column */
    protected $fillable = [/* describe column */];

    public function items() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }
}
```

I already describe all of my model, as you can see all table (child) have some relation to each parent like :

`stockIn -> typeOfItem (relation between child and parent)`

`typeOfItem -> Item (relation between child and parent)`

`Item -> CommonUnit (relation between child and parent)`

so for the question is how to make some query to getting data in nesting relationship when I do search for all data in child or parent? I already made the query but the result is not same with my expectation or null, it can be said that.

**StockInController**

```
$getData = StockIn::with(['type_of_items' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_type_item', 'type_id_item', 'code_type_of_item', 'type_of_item')
            ->with(['items' => function ($query) {
                $query->select('id_item', 'item_id_common_unit', 'name_item')
                ->with(['common_units' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id_common_unit', 'name_unit');
                }]);
            }]);
        }])
        ->with(['stock_out_left_join' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_stock_out', 'stock_out_id_stock_in');
        }])
        ->whereHas('type_of_items', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('code_type_of_item', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->whereHas('type_of_items.items', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->orWhere('name_item', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->whereHas('type_of_items.items.common_units', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->orWhere('name_unit', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->orWhere('created_by', 'like', "%{$search}%")
        ->orWhere('edited_by', 'like', "%{$search}%")
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Oh ya I will send example data for my query in this bellow :

[image]

but when I do search with some keyword is not worked, for example when I do type "adaptor", the result is empty or nothing show on my data, so what I must to do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for a while I was think about my problem finally I got the answer. Okay for  sharing to everyone I will explain a little bit for the answer.

So the query what I wrote on the controller, I change into this :

```
$getData = StockIn::with(['type_of_items' => function ($type_of_item) {
            $type_of_item->select('id_type_item', 'type_id_item', 'code_type_of_item', 'type_of_item')
            ->with(['items' => function ($item) {
                $item->select('id_item', 'item_id_common_unit', 'name_item')
                ->with(['common_units' => function ($common_unit) {
                    $common_unit->select('id_common_unit', 'name_unit');
                }]);
            }]);
        }])
        ->with(['stock_out_left_join' => function ($stock_out_left_join) {
            $stock_out_left_join->select('id_stock_out', 'stock_out_id_stock_in');
        }])
        ->whereHas('type_of_items', function ($type_of_items_search) use ($search) {
            $type_of_items_search->where('code_type_of_item', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('type_of_item', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->orWhereHas('type_of_items.items', function ($items_search) use ($search) {
            $items_search->where('name_item', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->orWhereHas('type_of_items.items.common_units', function ($common_units_search) use ($search) {
            $common_units_search->where('name_unit', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->orWhere('created_by', 'like', "%{$search}%")
        ->orWhere('edited_by', 'like', "%{$search}%")
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

As you can see my new query has a new parameter in every `with` function and I was naming all the parameter with different name, and not like first name before `query`, so the problem is the ambiguous paramater in every single `with` function because this query based on `nested relation` so I must make the parameter name different each other. Or you want make them into split one by one and not using the nested `with` function you can use this query too, I put on this bellow :

```
$getData = StockIn::with(['type_of_items' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_type_item', 'type_id_item', 'code_type_of_item', 'type_of_item');
        }])
        ->with(['type_of_items.items' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_item', 'item_id_common_unit', 'name_item');
        }])
        ->with(['type_of_items.items.common_units' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_common_unit', 'name_unit');
        }])
        ->with(['stock_out_left_join' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_stock_out', 'stock_out_id_stock_in');
        }])
        ->whereHas('type_of_items', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('code_type_of_item', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('type_of_item', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->orWhereHas('type_of_items.items', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('name_item', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->orWhereHas('type_of_items.items.common_units', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('name_unit', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->orWhere('created_by', 'like', "%{$search}%")
        ->orWhere('edited_by', 'like', "%{$search}%")
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

I already tried that query and it's work too (with the same name parameter in every single `with` function).